# Is TensorFlow.Data.Dataset the same as DatasetV1Adapter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

When I use:

```
training_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(SomeTrainingDirectoryIterator, (tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

I expect for it to return a Tensorflow Dataset, but instead, training_ds is a DatasetV1Adapter object.  Are they essentially the same thing?  If not could I convert the DatasetV1Adapter to a Tf.Data.Dataset object?

Also, what is the best way to view loop over and view my dataset?  If I were to call:

```
def show_batch(dataset):
    for batch, head in dataset.take(1):
        for labels, value in batch.items():
            print("{:20s}: {}".format(labels, value.numpy()))
```

With training_ds as my dataset, I am thrown this error:

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'items'

UPDATE:
I upgraded my TensorFlow version from 1.14 to 2.0. and now the Dataset is of a FlatMapDataset.  But this is still not my expected return object, why am I not being returned a regular tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: Using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() indeed produces a FlatMapDataset as it was supposed to do. What do you mean by a regular tf.data.Dataset? according to the TF documentation, FlatMapDataset can be used as a regular tf.data.Dataset. What exactly you are referring to achieve"? Your error seems to be a different problem with eager execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Tensorflow 2.0 (or below) `from_generator` will give you `DatasetV1Adapter`. For the Tensorflow version greater than 2.0 `from_generator` will give you `FlatMapDataset`.

The error you are facing is not related to the type of dataset `from_generator` returns, but with the way you are printing the dataset. `batch.items()` works if the `from_generator` is generating the data of `<class 'dict'>` type.

**Example 1 -** Here I am using `from_generator` to create `<class 'tuple'>` type data. So If I print using `batch.items()`, then it throws the error you are facing. You can simply use `list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())` to print the dataset OR `dataset.take(1).as_numpy_iterator()` to print required number of records, here as it is `take(1)`, it prints just one record. Have added print statements in the code to explain better. You can find details in the Output.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import itertools

def gen():
  for i in itertools.count(1):
    yield (i, [1] * i)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     gen,
     (tf.int64, tf.int64),
     (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None])))

print("tf.data.Dataset type is:",dataset,"\n")

for batch in dataset.take(1):
  print("My type is of:",type(batch),"\n")

# This Works
print("Lets print just the first row in dataset :","\n",list(dataset.take(1).as_numpy_iterator()),"\n")

# This won't work because we have not created dict 
print("Lets print using the batch.items() :")
for batch in dataset.take(1):
  for m1,m2 in batch.items():
      print("{:20s}: {}".format(m1, m2))
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
tf.data.Dataset type is: <FlatMapDataset shapes: ((), (None,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)> 

My type is of: <class 'tuple'> 

Lets print just the first row in dataset : 
 [(1, array([1]))] 

Lets print using the batch.items() :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-27bbc2c21d24> in <module>()
     24 print("Lets print using the batch.items() :")
     25 for batch in dataset.take(1):
---> 26   for m1,m2 in batch.items():
     27       print("{:20s}: {}".format(m1, m2))

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**Example 2 -** Here I am using `from_generator` to create `<class 'dict'>` type data. So If I print using `batch.items()`, then it works without any issues. Being said that, you can simply use `list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())` to print the dataset. Have added print statements in the code to explain better. You can find details in the Output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 100
# dictionary of arrays:
metadata = {'m1': tf.zeros(shape=(N,2)), 'm2': tf.ones(shape=(N,3,5))}
num_samples = N

def meta_dict_gen():
    for i in range(num_samples):
        ls = {}
        for key, val in metadata.items():
            ls[key] = val[i]
        yield ls

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    meta_dict_gen,
    output_types={k: tf.float32 for k in metadata},
    output_shapes={'m1': (2,), 'm2': (3, 5)})

print("tf.data.Dataset type is:",dataset,"\n")

for batch in dataset.take(1):
  print("My type is of:",type(batch),"\n")

print("Lets print just the first row in dataset :","\n",list(dataset.take(1).as_numpy_iterator()),"\n")

print("Lets print using the batch.items() :")
for batch in dataset.take(1):
  for m1, m2 in batch.items():
    print("{:2s}: {}".format(m1, m2))
```

**Output -**

```
tf.data.Dataset type is: <FlatMapDataset shapes: {m1: (2,), m2: (3, 5)}, types: {m1: tf.float32, m2: tf.float32}> 

My type is of: <class 'dict'> 

Lets print just the first row in dataset : 
 [{'m1': array([0., 0.], dtype=float32), 'm2': array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)}] 

Lets print using the batch.items() :
m1: [0. 0.]
m2: [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @theMoreYouNgo - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.